# Return certain element from Set based on ranking

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I'm working on a project where I have a number of unique strings in a Set (or it could be an array). I'm trying to write a function that returns the string in that Set with the highest "value".

The "value" is determined by a hierarchy that contains a number of other strings, each residing within their own level. For example:

**Level 1 (Highest)**
A1, A2, A3, A4 ...

**Level 2**
B1, B2, B3, B4 ...

**Level 3 (Lowest)**
C1, C2,C3 ...

So for example, if the strings in my initial Set are [C2, C3, A2, B1], then I'd expect A2 to be returned. In situations where there is a "value" tie, then the first string could be returned.

One potential solution might be to iterate through that hierarchy structure (which would maybe be an array of arrays) starting at the highest level, then checking to see if the currently iterated-on value is contained in the Set. If it is, then that value could be returned.

Can anyone think of a better way to structure / accomplish this though? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general approach sounds reasonable, though a slightly better way would be to not have a hierarchy of *arrays*, but a hierarchy of *sets*. Checking whether an item exists in a Set is `O(1)`, unlike an array, which is `O(n)`. This way, the overall algorithm is `O(n ^ 2)`, not `O(n ^ 3)`.

```
for (const levelSet of hierarchy) {
  for (const str of inputStrings) {
    if (levelSet.has(str)) return str;
  }
}
```

Unless the level can be predicted from a string's structure *without* iterating through the hierarchy, I don't think there's a less complex solution.

If the level *can* be predicted without iterating - for example, if a string that starts with A is in the first hierarchy, and so on - it can probably be made less expensive by iterating over each string in the input instead, and not touching the hierarchy structure. (depending on the computation involved in determining the hierarchy level from a given string)

Comment: I would expect `inputStrings.size` to be larger than `levelSet.size`, in which case it would make more sense to iterate over `levelSet` (which could also be an array in that case) and then test for `inputStrings.has(levelElement)`. Instead of saying `O(n²)`, we should separately name the number of levels, the average number of elements per level, and the size of the input.